# Estimating memory requirements for xgboost during inference

Tags: xgboost

Does anyone know how the memory requirements of xgboost scale at inference with number and depth of trees (`n_estimators` and `max_depth`)? These seem to be the hyperparameters that drive xgboost's memory consumption.

The reason I'm asking is that I'm trying to do hyperparameter tuning and I'd like to include a constraint on the hyperparameters based on the memory limitations of the machines we're using for inference.